# Put image on top of another image

Tags: html, css

I have a background. On top of that background, I have an image overlaying it at the top. What I'm trying to do is overlay the background with an image at the bottom of it:

Like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRs5c.png]

HTML:

```
<div class="scroll-bg">
  <img src="img/scroll_top.gif" style="position:absolute" /><!-- TOP OVERLAY IMAGE -->
      <div class="scroll-bg-img">
        <div class="scroll-content">
        <center><img src="img/recent_news.gif" /></center>
        <div style="width:100%;margin-top:15px">
          <div style="margin-top:10px;color:black">
            <p>TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT MORE TEXT</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
   </div>       
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.scroll-bg {
    width: 810px;
    float: right;
}

.scroll-content {
    width: 765px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}

.scroll-bg-img {
    background-image: url(img/scroll_bg.gif);
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 795px; 
    height: 1000px;
    margin-top: 40px; 
    margin-left: 7px;
    padding-top: 15px;
}
```

Comment: "on top of the background except at the bottom of the background" what?

Comment: As in, overlaying the background image, at the bottom of the background image.

Comment: [http://i.imgur.com/WgSNUTp.png](http://i.imgur.com/WgSNUTp.png) What I'm trying to do is add the bottom image.

Comment: Is that entire box the `scroll-bg`?

Answer (score 2):

Your top and bottom elements need to be inside background.

#### HTML

```
<div class="background">
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="bottom"></div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.background {
    position: relative;
    background: url("path/to/bg.png");
}

.top {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    background: url("path/to/top.png");
}

.bottom {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    background: url("path/to/bottom.png");
}
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/TrRcc/

Comment: What if I wanted to make the background thinner by, say, 10px on each side?

Comment: Try adding margins, for example, `margin: 0 10px`, to the `.background` declaration. http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/TrRcc/2/

Answer (score 1):

If you can't change the structure of your `html` then I guess you can set your `.scroll-bg` to be relative:

```
.scroll-bg {
    width: 810px;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
}
```

and fix the position of the second img:

```
.scroll-content img {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Would it work with you?

Comment: then you have to change the structure of your html and divs

Answer (score 0):

Use a relative wrapper, something like this;

**CSS**

```
.imgWrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}

.imgWrapper img {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    display: block;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="imgWrapper">
    <img src="img1.png" />
    <img src="img2.png" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You basically have your answer in your own HTML.

```
<div class="scroll-bg">
    <img src="img/scroll_top.gif" style="position:absolute" /><!-- TOP OVERLAY IMAGE -->
    <div class="scroll-bg-img">
        <div class="scroll-content">
            <center><img src="img/recent_news.gif" /></center>
            <div style="width:100%;margin-top:15px">
                <div style="margin-top:10px;color:black">
                    <p>TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT MORE TEXT</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <img src="img/scroll_bottom.gif" style="position:absolute" /><!-- BOTTOM OVERLAY IMAGE -->
</div>
```

You just have to set the position of each image appropriately so that one is on the top, and one is on the bottom.

Comment: That didn't work. It still places it below the background image, rather than overlaying the background image.

Comment: It *will* work if you do what I said, and *position each image appropriately* using CSS.

Comment: I've tried changing the positions around and none have worked. :/